# Passing file as Part in servlets

Tags: file, jsp, servlets

I need some help with passing files in servlets. I have a JSP code with multiform which uploads the file. I can get it as a Java Part like that:

```
Part cab = request.getPart("cab");
```

And it works fine, but I would like to pass that file to another servlet. How can I do it? request.setAttribute doesn't seem to work for me, and there is no such thing as ".setPart()". Do i have to convert this Part to String and then send it using setAttribute()?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Add more info. Could't unserstand what are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass your file object using

```
request.setAttribute("objectName", cab); //here cab is object.
RequestDispatcher reqDispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("pathToyourServlet2");
reqDispatcher.forward(req, res);
```

and retrieve the same on another servlet via getAttribute method.

```
request.getAttribute("objectName");
```